# ¿Esta clase esta correcta?

Tags: php, mvc

Soy nuevo en PHP, un instructor realizó esta clase Controlador, es un MVC, y puso un `__Hospital(){}` sin usarlo, ¿es necesario eso?

```
class Hospital{
    private $cod;
    private $nom;
    private $dir;

    public function __Hospital() {

    }

    public function _Hospital($cod, $nom, $dir) {
        $this->cod = $cod;
        $this->nom = $nom;
        $this->dir = $dir;
    }

    public function getCod() {
        return $this->cod;
    }

    public function getNom() {
        return $this->nom;
    }

    public function getDir() {
        return $this->dir;
    }

    public function setCod($cod) {
        $this->cod = $cod;
    }

    public function setNom($nom) {
        $this->nom = $nom;
    }

    public function setDir($dir) {
        $this->dir = $dir;
    }
}
```

Comment: Si, parece correcto

Comment: por que? @GermánMartínez

Comment: no le veo utilidad ya que de hecho tiene 2 métodos con nombre similar pero uno tiene doble guión bajo y otra solo uno

Comment: salvo que lo use como una especie de constructor

Comment: @ShadowPaz no hay solo dos formas de constructor? una usando __construct()  y la otra es poniendo el mismo nombre de la clase?

Comment: pues la idea del constructor como método mágico de PHP es inicializar las propiedades de la clase, no veo por que deberáis declarar un método que simule eso con el mismo nombre de la clase a menos que uses la clase para múltiples tareas y necesites diferenciar cada uno

Comment: no es necesario porque declaras un constructor default de phpmas info aqui http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php

Answer (score 9, accepted):

La idea central de los constructores como métodos mágicos en especifico en PHP; es inicializar el valor de las propiedades que identificar o son pertenecientes a una clase.

**EJEMPLO**

```
<?php

class Padre{
   protected $name;
   protected $edad;

  public function __construct($name, $edad){
    $this->name = $name;
    $this->edad = $edad;
  }
}
```

Ahora no es tanto que sea incorrecto o no, si no mas bien como el interprete de PHP lo va a leer;

Cito:

> A partir de PHP 5.3.3, los métodos con el mismo nombre que el último
>   elemento de una clase en un nombre de espacios no serán más tratados
>   como un constructor. Este cambio no afecta a clases sin espacio de
>   nombres.

Ejemplo de la cita

```
<?php
namespace Foo;
class Bar {
    public function Bar() {
        // Tratado como constructor en PHP 5.3.0 - 5.3.2
        // Tratado como método regular a partir de PHP 5.3.3
    }
}
```

[Fuente de consulta](http://php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.decon.php)

Este modo de declarar un constructor donde posee el mismo nombre de la clase, es común por ejemplo aunque no limitado a lenguajes como Java; donde lo siguiente es válido

```
public class Human
{
  public Human(type param1, type param2, ...)
  {
  }
  ......
}
```

Donde de hecho si lo omites te marcará un error al momento de tratar de compilar el proyecto similar a: `invalid method declaration`